# Why would a for loop unexpectedly incomplete its iterations in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

The `ProjectModel` `List` contained six items during the test. The first `for` loop does not go into the second iteration, thus creating only three card elements. I used break points to step through the code and found the values are what is expected.  What did I miss?

```
@model List<ProjectModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Projects";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        @{
            int columns = 0;
            @for (int rows = (Model.Count / 3) + (Model.Count % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1); rows > 0; rows--)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @for (int k = columns; k < Model.Count && k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body" style="height:8em">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">@Model[columns].ProjectName</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Owned by @Model[columns].ProjectOwner</p>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model[columns].ProjectUrl</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                    @foreach (string outcome in Model[columns].Outcomes)
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item">@outcome</li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        columns++;
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to show three items in one row.If so,you can do like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            @{
                int columns = 0;
                @for (int rows = 0; rows < (Model.Count / 3) + (Model.Count % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1); rows++)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        @for (int k = columns; k < Model.Count && k >=rows*3&&k<(rows+1)*3; k++)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body" style="height:8em">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">@Model[columns].ProjectName</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Owned by @Model[columns].ProjectOwner</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">@Model[columns].ProjectUrl</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        @foreach (string outcome in Model[columns].Outcomes)
                                        {
                                            <li class="list-group-item">@outcome</li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            columns++;
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

result(I use fake data to test):
[image]